# JS array of objects destructuring?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a react project I need to simplify an array of objects.

I've an array of objects coming from wp rest api axios request. Inside objects there are objects. I would like to "remove" this nested object in order to have this **:**

```
   [
      {
        "id": 101,
        "title": "CTC20180018",
        "fielda": "valuea",
        "fieldb": "valueb",
        "fieldc": "valuec"
      },
      {
        "id": 102,
        "title": "D2021063365",
        "fielda": "valuea",
        "fieldb": "valueb",
        "fieldc": "valuec"
      },
      ...
    ]
```

What is the best solution ? `.map()` the array and use `destructuring` ?

The original array **:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 101,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "CTC20180018"
    },
    "acf": {
      "fielda": "valuea",
      "fieldb": "valueb",
      "fieldc": "valuec"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "D2021063365"
    },
    "acf": {
      "fielda": "valuea",
      "fieldb": "valueb",
      "fieldc": "valuec"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: if you know how to do the map go for it. this is a good use case of map

Comment: Particular prop-names such as `acf` and `rendered` need to be removed - in order to achieve the target structure, is that correct?

Comment: I'm a newby... don't know how to map this array to destructure sub objects... ;)

Comment: yes @jsN00b it's what i want to do !

Comment: Please try this: `const newArr = origArr.map(obj => ({ id: obj.id, title: obj.title.rendered, ...obj.acf}));` Or, you may use kiranvj's solution below. It uses destructuring the iterator.

Comment: Thanks @jsN00b it's working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below using `map`, [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 101,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "CTC20180018"
    },
    "acf": {
      "fielda": "valuea",
      "fieldb": "valueb",
      "fieldc": "valuec"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 102,
    "title": {
      "rendered": "D2021063365"
    },
    "acf": {
      "fielda": "valuea",
      "fieldb": "valueb",
      "fieldc": "valuec"
    }
  }
]

const result = data.map(({
  id,
  title,
  acf
}) => ({
  id: id,
  title: title.rendered,
  ...acf
}));

console.log(result);
```